# Output formatting in array and how to take values outside of for loop

Tags: java, arrays, output-formatting

I want the output to appear after the dotted line.Sum of each column must appear beneath its column,i tried inserting the result in an array but i am not able to take it outside of for loop.

```
public class SumOfColumn 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    int i,j;
    int a[][]={{22,33,44,11},{33,55,77,11},{44,11,88,55},{33,55,22,77}};
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
         int sum=0;
         for(j=0;j<4;j++)
         {
             System.out.print(a[i][j]+ "\t" );
             sum = sum + a[j][i];
         }
    System.out.println(sum);    
    System.out.println();
    }
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
}
```

This is the output where result is appearing in front of rows i want the result below each column and below the dotted line

```
22  33  44  11  132

33  55  77  11  154

44  11  88  55  231

33  55  22  77  154

----------------
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this try using System.out.println(); before you print sum here's complete code:   public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     int i,j;
     int a[][]={{22,33,44,11},{33,55,77,11},{44,11,88,55},{33,55,22,77}};
     System.out.println("-------------------");
     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
          int sum=0;
          for(j=0;j<4;j++)
          {
              System.out.print(a[i][j]+ "\t" );
              sum = sum + a[j][i];
          }
          System.out.println();
     System.out.println(sum);    
     System.out.println();
     }
         
     }
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a result value outside the scope of of the for() loop. Something like this oughta do it (not tested, though)

```
public class SumOfColumn 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    int i,j;
    int a[][]={{22,33,44,11},{33,55,77,11},{44,11,88,55},{33,55,22,77}};
    int res[]={0,0,0,0};
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
         int sum=0;
         for(j=0;j<4;j++)
         {
             System.out.print(a[i][j]+ "\t" );
             sum = sum + a[j][i];
         }
        res[i]=sum;
        System.out.println(sum);    
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(res[i]+ "\t" );
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
}
```